# how to run multiple command in single line pssh?

Tags: linux, sh, pssh

I want to run multiple command like command1, command2 , command3 in single line how to do?

i tried following

```
pssh -Pi --user XXXX -h host.txt  -x "-oStrictHostKeyChecking=no" ls date
```

i am getting following error

```
Stderr: ls: cannot access date: No such file or directory
```

Comment: can you able to run other commands?

Comment: yes it worked for me after small modification pssh -Pi --user XXXX -h host.txt  -x "-oStrictHostKeyChecking=no" ls;date;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following worked for me after trying few combinations

```
pssh -Pi --user XXXX -h host.txt  -x "-oStrictHostKeyChecking=no" ls;date;
```